# Spark : Execute python script with Spark based on Hadoop Multinode

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing

I'm looking for use `Spark` based on `Hadoop Multinodes` and I have a question about my pythonic script with cluster mode.

#### My Configuration :

I have into my Hadoop Cluster :

- 1 Namenode (master)
- 2 Datanodes (slaves)

So I would like to execute my script in Python in order to use this cluster. I know that Spark could be used as standalone mode, but I would like to use my nodes.

#### My python script :

It's a very simple script which let to count words in my text.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(' '))
words_with_1 = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
word_counts = words_with_1.reduceByKey(lambda count1, count2: count1 + count2)
result = word_counts.collect()

for (word, count) in result:
    print word.encode("utf8"), count
```

#### My Spark command :

In order to use Spark, I do :

```
time ./bin/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 /home/hduser/count.py /data.txt
```

But, this command lets to execute Spark in standalone mode right ?
How I can execute Spark using my Hadoop Cluster (e.g yarn) and make parallel and distributed computing on my cluster ?

I tried :

```
time ./bin/spark-submit --master yarn /home/hduser/count.py /data.txt
```

And I get issues :

```
2018-03-15 10:13:14 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-03-15 10:13:15 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Running Spark version 2.3.0
2018-03-15 10:13:15 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Submitted application: count.py
2018-03-15 10:13:15 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: hduser
2018-03-15 10:13:15 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: hduser
2018-03-15 10:13:15 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2018-03-15 10:13:15 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2018-03-15 10:13:15 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hduser); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hduser)$
2018-03-15 10:13:16 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 40388.
2018-03-15 10:13:16 INFO  SparkEnv:54 - Registering MapOutputTracker
2018-03-15 10:13:16 INFO  SparkEnv:54 - Registering BlockManagerMaster
2018-03-15 10:13:16 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
2018-03-15 10:13:16 INFO  BlockManagerMasterEndpoint:54 - BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
2018-03-15 10:13:16 INFO  DiskBlockManager:54 - Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-b131528e-849e-4ba7-94fe-c552572f12fc
2018-03-15 10:13:16 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore started with capacity 413.9 MB
2018-03-15 10:13:16 INFO  SparkEnv:54 - Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  log:192 - Logging initialized @5400ms
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  Server:346 - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  Server:414 - Started @5667ms
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  AbstractConnector:278 - Started ServerConnector@4f835332{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2f867b0c{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2a0105b7{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3fd04590{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2637750b{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@439f0c7{/stages,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3978d915{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@596dc76d{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7054d173{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@47b526bb{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7896fc75{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2fd54632{/storage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@79dcd5f2{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1732b48c{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5888874b{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5de9bebe{/environment,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@428593b4{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4011c9bc{/executors,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5cbfbc2a{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4c33f54d{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@22c5d74c{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6cd7b681{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5ee342f2{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4d68a347{/api,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e878af1{/jobs/job/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@590aa379{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2018-03-15 10:13:17 INFO  SparkUI:54 - Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://master:4040
2018-03-15 10:13:19 INFO  RMProxy:98 - Connecting to ResourceManager at master/172.30.10.64:8050
2018-03-15 10:13:20 INFO  Client:54 - Requesting a new application from cluster with 3 NodeManagers
2018-03-15 10:13:20 INFO  Client:54 - Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
2018-03-15 10:13:20 INFO  Client:54 - Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
2018-03-15 10:13:20 INFO  Client:54 - Setting up container launch context for our AM
2018-03-15 10:13:20 INFO  Client:54 - Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
2018-03-15 10:13:20 INFO  Client:54 - Preparing resources for our AM container
2018-03-15 10:13:24 WARN  Client:66 - Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
2018-03-15 10:13:29 INFO  Client:54 - Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-bbfad5cb-3d29-4f45-a1a9-2e37f2c76606/__spark_libs__580552500091841387.zip -> hdfs://master:54310/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1521023754917_0007/__s$
2018-03-15 10:13:33 INFO  Client:54 - Uploading resource file:/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://master:54310/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1521023754917_0007/pyspark.zip
2018-03-15 10:13:33 INFO  Client:54 - Uploading resource file:/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip -> hdfs://master:54310/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1521023754917_0007/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip
2018-03-15 10:13:34 INFO  Client:54 - Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-bbfad5cb-3d29-4f45-a1a9-2e37f2c76606/__spark_conf__7840630163677580304.zip -> hdfs://master:54310/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1521023754917_0007/__$
2018-03-15 10:13:34 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: hduser
2018-03-15 10:13:34 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: hduser
2018-03-15 10:13:34 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2018-03-15 10:13:34 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2018-03-15 10:13:34 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hduser); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hduser)$
2018-03-15 10:13:34 INFO  Client:54 - Submitting application application_1521023754917_0007 to ResourceManager
2018-03-15 10:13:34 INFO  YarnClientImpl:251 - Submitted application application_1521023754917_0007
2018-03-15 10:13:34 INFO  SchedulerExtensionServices:54 - Starting Yarn extension services with app application_1521023754917_0007 and attemptId None
2018-03-15 10:13:35 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:35 INFO  Client:54 -
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: N/A
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: default
         start time: 1521105214408
         final status: UNDEFINED
         tracking URL: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1521023754917_0007/
         user: hduser
2018-03-15 10:13:36 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:37 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:38 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:39 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:40 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:41 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:42 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:43 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:44 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:45 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:46 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:47 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:48 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:49 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:50 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1521023754917_0007 (state: FAILED)
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  Client:54 -
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: Application application_1521023754917_0007 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1521023754917_0007_000002 exited with  exitCode: -103
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://master:8088/cluster/app/application_1521023754917_0007Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Container [pid=9363,containerID=container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 147.7 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing cont$
Dump of the process-tree for container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001 :
        |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
        |- 9369 9363 9363 9363 (java) 454 16 2250776576 37073 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -server -Xmx512m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1521023754917_0007/co$
        |- 9363 9361 9363 9363 (bash) 0 0 12869632 742 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -server -Xmx512m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1521023754917_0$

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: default
         start time: 1521105214408
         final status: FAILED
         tracking URL: http://master:8088/cluster/app/application_1521023754917_0007
         user: hduser
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  Client:54 - Deleted staging directory hdfs://master:54310/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1521023754917_0007
2018-03-15 10:13:51 ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  AbstractConnector:318 - Stopped Spark@4f835332{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  SparkUI:54 - Stopped Spark web UI at http://master:4040
2018-03-15 10:13:51 WARN  YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint:66 - Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  YarnClientSchedulerBackend:54 - Shutting down all executors
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint:54 - Asking each executor to shut down
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  SchedulerExtensionServices:54 - Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices
(serviceOption=None,
 services=List(),
 started=false)
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  YarnClientSchedulerBackend:54 - Stopped
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint:54 - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore cleared
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  BlockManager:54 - BlockManager stopped
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - BlockManagerMaster stopped
2018-03-15 10:13:51 WARN  MetricsSystem:66 - Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
2018-03-15 10:13:51 INFO  OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:54 - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2018-03-15 10:13:52 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Successfully stopped SparkContext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hduser/count.py", line 4, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 180, in _do_init
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 270, in _initialize_context
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1428, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2018-03-15 10:13:52 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-03-15 10:13:52 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-bbfad5cb-3d29-4f45-a1a9-2e37f2c76606
2018-03-15 10:13:52 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-f5d31d54-e456-4fcb-bf48-9f950233ad4b
```

I'm getting all the time `FAILED` when I want to use my cluster with Spark

[image]

Finally I tried :

```
time ./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster /home/hduser/count.py /data.txt
```

But I get one more time issues.

I don't understand something ? I'm very new with Big Data so it's possible :/
**EDIT :**

This is what I obtain with : `yarn application -status application_1521023754917_0007`

```
18/03/15 10:52:07 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/172.30.10.64:8050
18/03/15 10:52:07 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Application Report : 
    Application-Id : application_1521023754917_0007
    Application-Name : count.py
    Application-Type : SPARK
    User : hduser
    Queue : default
    Start-Time : 1521105214408
    Finish-Time : 1521105231067
    Progress : 0%
    State : FAILED
    Final-State : FAILED
    Tracking-URL : http://master:8088/cluster/app/application_1521023754917_0007
    RPC Port : -1
    AM Host : N/A
    Aggregate Resource Allocation : 16329 MB-seconds, 15 vcore-seconds
    Diagnostics : Application application_1521023754917_0007 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1521023754917_0007_000002 exited with  exitCode: -103
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://master:8088/cluster/app/application_1521023754917_0007Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Container [pid=9363,containerID=container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 147.7 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.1 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 9369 9363 9363 9363 (java) 454 16 2250776576 37073 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -server -Xmx512m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1521023754917_0007/container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001/tmp -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.5/logs/userlogs/application_1521023754917_0007/container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher --arg master:40388 --properties-file /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1521023754917_0007/container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties 
    |- 9363 9361 9363 9363 (bash) 0 0 12869632 742 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -server -Xmx512m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1521023754917_0007/container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001/tmp -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.5/logs/userlogs/application_1521023754917_0007/container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher --arg 'master:40388' --properties-file /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1521023754917_0007/container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties 1> /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.5/logs/userlogs/application_1521023754917_0007/container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001/stdout 2> /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.5/logs/userlogs/application_1521023754917_0007/container_1521023754917_0007_02_000001/stderr 

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Comment: `--master spark://master:7077` does run the job distributed. Not sure about the other errors, but the first case should be fine.

Comment: It says `Error initializing SparkContext.`. Also, you can use `yarn application -status <applicationID>` to check more details.

Comment: @BenWatson Ok, but this command let to use autonome Spark cluster manager. Not distributed jobs.

Comment: @philantrovert I edited my question with the result from your command.

Comment: It will be distributed on your cluster; you're submitting the job to the Spark master, which is responsible for several datanodes. The master will oversee running the job on the datanodes. Spark abstracts this away from you so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @BenWatson But if the job is distributed, why I don't see the job in my Hadoop overview ? I don't know if Spark takes account my namenode and both datanodes. How I could see if datanodes are well-used ?

Comment: Aren't you seeing it in the Spark UI? https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-webui.html

Comment: @BenWatson I just have this : http://www.image-heberg.fr/files/15211081401660297995.png Is it the same thing ?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's the one

Answer (score 1):

for me this spark submit run the python on all spark nodes:

```
spark-submit --master yarn 
             --deploy-mode cluster 
             --num-executors 1 
             --driver-memory 2g 
             --executor-memory 1g 
             --executor-cores 1 
             hdfs://<host>:<port>/home/hduser/count.py /data.txt
```

The Spark environment need to be extended with: 
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/bin/python

Furthermore the py file need to be located on hdfs so that all spark nodes in the cluster can read it. The py file need to be accessible for the spark user.

Comment: It doesn't work and `yarn-client` is deprecated for 2.x version. Then I would like to use spark as cluster deploying mode.

Comment: sorry, you right. i have updated my post, please let me know if it worked for you ...

Comment: Files are stored in my HDFS `hdfs://master:54310/user/hduser` but I have `Client:54 - Application report for application_1521112157923_0011 (state:FAILED)` after some ACCEPTED steps ..

Answer (score 0):

you have to first locate the py scrip in the HDFS location. With the name node correct URL

like  hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://hostname:1543/

if you see your file is reflecting in the screen then this is the correct path.

Next execute

/bin/spark-submit --master yarn hdfs://COMPLETEHOSTNAME:1543/count.py /data.txt

it will surely work.